# Log4perl category as log file name

Tags: log4perl

I'm sure I'm being dim and missing the obvious but is there a simple way of using the current category as the filename in a config file without resorting to a subroutine call?

So that in the following one could use `${category}.log` instead of repeating `bin.nh.tpp` in the filename line

```
log4perl.logger.**bin.nh.tpp**=INFO, BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE

log4perl.appender.BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE=Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE.filename=${LOGS}/nh/**bin.nh.tpp**.log
log4perl.appender.BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE.mode=append
log4perl.appender.BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE.layout=PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.BIN_NH_TPP_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %F{1} %L %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat more involved than a subroutine, I'm afraid. Subroutines in l4p conf files allow for including variables known at conf file parsing time, e.g. the time/date or a user id. You can't modify log time behavior that way.

The easiest way I can think of right now to accomplish what you want is a custom appender like

```
package FileByCategoryAppender;

use warnings;
use strict;
use base qw( Log::Log4perl::Appender::File );

sub new {
    my( $class, %options ) = @_;

    $options{filename } = "no-category.log";
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new( %options );
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub log {
    my( $self, %params ) = @_;

    my $category = $params{ log4p_category };
    $self->SUPER::file_switch( $category . ".log" );
    $self->SUPER::log( %params );
}

1;
```

and then use it in your script like

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Log::Log4perl qw( get_logger );

my $conf = q(
log4perl.category         = WARN, Logfile
log4perl.appender.Logfile = FileByCategoryAppender
log4perl.appender.Logfile.create_at_logtime = 1
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout = \
  Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %F{1} %L> %m %n
);

Log::Log4perl::init(\$conf);

my $logger = get_logger("Bar::Twix");
$logger->error("twix error");

$logger = get_logger("Bar::Mars");
$logger->error("mars error");
```

which will result in two log files being created at log time:

```
# Bar.Mars.log
2012/11/18 11:12:12 t 21> mars error
```

and

```
# Bar.Twix.log
2012/11/18 11:12:12 t 21> twix error
```